# How to assign data from CSV into Object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv

so far I have this one which works really good.

```
 private static MovieItem readCSV(string path)
    {
      var yourData = File.ReadAllLines(path)
                   .Skip(1)
                   .Select(x => x.Split(';'))
                   .Select(x => new Movie
                   {

                     GUID = x[0],
                     Title = x[1],
                     ISBN = x[2],
                     CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
                     AuthorInformation = new AuthorInformation()
                     {
                       Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                       Name = x[4],
                       Address = x[5],
                       Age = x[6]
                     }
                   }).ToArray();

      return yourData[0];

    }
```

My question is, is there a better way to assign the object?
So far I have like `GUID = x[0], Title = x[1]` and so on... it's not good because the header in the first row can change, so I want to be flexible.
Is there a way to assign e.g. GUID to the CSV header named GUID?
Like looking for the header name and if it is equal GUID, assign the content to GUID?

CSV File:
[image]

Comment: You already read *all* lines but return only the first one. Return `yourData` instead of `yourData[0]`

Comment: Oh yeah. How can I return all? Do I have to add all the Objects into a List and return as a List? so like `private static List<MovieItem> readCSV(string path) { ... return yourData; }` ?

Comment: I already wrote what to do. Return `yourDate`. Literally - `return yourData` and fix the return type

Comment: 1- Make a class and name it "Movie" or whatever convenient. It's fields would be GUID, Title, ISBN, etc..
2-Read your CSV file onetime where you will read the first line only and split it to a string[] array -your splitter is ";"- and store the index of each field to a variable (Switch statement would be very helpful here)
3-Read it again skipping the first line. Split by "\r\n" this time. Use a loop to go through all the lines, Split by ";" again, and inside this loop instantiate a Movie() object with corresponding data cuz now you know the index of each data item -the variables I mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've commented your question that already but here's a sample code:

1- Make a class and name it "Book" or whatever convenient. It's fields would be GUID, Title, ISBN, etc..

```
public class Book //I'm showing only one field of the class
{
    private string title;
    public string Title { get; set;}

    public Book() {}
}
```

2-Read your CSV file onetime where you will read the first line only and split it to a string[] array -your splitter is ";"- and store the index of each field to a variable (Switch statement would be very helpful here)

```
    public struct Headers   //use it to store the index of each field in the file only title is shown here
    {
        public int title;
    }
    string[] rowSplitter = new string[] { "\r\n" };
    string[] colSplitter = new string[] { ";" };


//Inside a method for reading the file use the following code    
    string[] csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvFile).Split(rowSplitter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string[] headerRow = csvData [0].Split(colSplitter, StringSplitOptions.None);
    Headers column = new Headers();
    for (int i = 0; i < headerRow.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (headerRow[i].ToLower())
            {
                case "title":
                    column.title = i;
                    break;
            }
    }
```

3- Use a loop to go through all the lines, Split by ";" again, and inside this loop instantiate a Book() object with corresponding data cuz now you know the index of each data item -the variables I mentioned.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < csvData.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] currentRow = csvData[i].Split(colSplitter, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Book bookItem = new Book();
        bookItem.Title = currentRow[column.title];
//Here you can do whatever you like with this bookItem on-the-fly or if you want to keep it to the end of your code add it to a list.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            //reading all the lines(rows) from the file.
            string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\CSV\test.csv"));

            DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
            string[] rowValues = null;
            DataRow dr = dtData.NewRow();

            //Creating columns
            if (rows.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string columnName in rows[0].Split(','))
                    dtData.Columns.Add(columnName.Replace(" ", "").ToLower());
            }

            //Creating row for each line.(except the first line, which contain column names)
            for (int row = 1; row < rows.Length; row++)
            {
                rowValues = rows[row].Split(',');
                dr = dtData.NewRow();
                dr.ItemArray = rowValues;
                dtData.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are acceptable if it's obvious how they answer the question. This is neither obvious nor answer the question at all. The OP didn't ask how to create a DataTable. This code doesn't even return the DataTable. Edit the answer and explain how it helps

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Actually it's the another best way to get data from csv file. That's why I suggested to Takuya2412

Comment: No, it's not nor is it obvious what it does. Just like the OP's code it loads the entire file in memory when it doesn't have to, generates a *lot* of temporary strings, and would fail if any fields were quoted to allow eg for commas in the values. Using a DataTable isn't an obvious solution, in fact libraries that read CSVs don't use them directly.